# Having trouble capturing storing strings in Perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

So I've been working around with this problem for a while now.

I have a file with one hundred FASTA sequences arranged like this:

>gi|192567|gb|AAA37417.1| cystic fibrosis transmembrane conductance regulator [Mus musculus]
MQKSPLEKASFISKLFFSWTTPILRKGYRHHLELSDIYQAPSADSADHLSEKLEREWDREQASKKNPQLIHALRRCFFWRFLFYGILLYLGEVTKAVQPVLLGRIIASYDPENKVERSIAIYLGIGLCLLFIVRTLLLHPAIFGLHRIGMQMRTAMFSLIYKKTLKLSSRVLDKISIGQLVSLLSNNLNKFDEGLALAHFIWIAPLQVTLLMGLLWDLLQFSAFCGLGLLIILVIFQAILGKMMVKYRDQRAAKINERLVITSEIIDNIYSVKAYCWESAMEKMIENLREVELKMTRKAAYMRFFTSSAFFFSGFFVVFLSVLPYTVINGIVLRKIFTTISFCIVLRMSVTRQFPTAVQIWYDSFGMIRKIQDFLQKQEYKVLEYNLMTTGIIMENVTAFWEEGFGELLQKAQQSNGDRKHSSDENNVSFSHLCLVGNPVLKNINLNIEKGEMLAITGSTGLGKTSLLMLILGELEASEGIIKHSGRVSFCSQFSWIMPGTIKENIIFGVSYDEYRYKSVVKACQLQQDITKFAEQDNTVLGEGGVTLSGGQRARISLARAVYKDADLYLLDSPFGYLDVFTEEQVFESCVCKLMANKTRILVTSKMEHLRKADKILILHQGTSYFYGTFSELQSLRPSFSSKLMGYDTFDQFTEERRSSILTETLRRFSVDDSSAPWSKPKQSFRQTGEVGEKRKNSILNSFSSVRKISIVQKTPLCIDGESDDLQEKRLSLVPDSEQGEAALPRSNMIATGPTFPGRRRQSVLDLMTFTPNSGSSNLQRTRTSIRKISLVPQISLNEVDVYSRRLSQDSTLNITEEINEEDLKECFLDDVIKIPPVTTWNTYLRYFTLHKGLLLVLIWCVLVFLVEVAASLFVLWLLKNNPVNSGNNGTKISNSSYVVIITSTSFYYIFYIYVGVADTLLALSLFRGLPLVHTLITASKILHRKMLHSILHAPMSTISKLKAGGILNRFSKDIAILDDFLPLTIFDFIQLVFIVIGAIIVVSALQPYIFLATVPGLVVFILLRAYFLHTAQQLKQLESEGRSPIFTHLVTSLKGLWTLRAFRRQTYFETLFHKALNLHTANWFMYLATLRWFQMRIDMIFVLFFIVVTFISILTTGEGEGTAGIILTLAMNIMSTLQWAVNSSIDTDSLMRSVSRVFKFIDIQTEESMYTQIIKELPREGSSDVLVIKNEHVKKSDIWPSGGEMVVKDLTVKYMDDGNAVLENISFSISPGQRVGLLGRTGSGKSTLLSAFLRMLNIKGDIEIDGVSWNSVTLQEWRKAFGVITQKVFIFSGTFRQNLDPNGKWKDEEIWKVADEVGLKSVIEQFPGQLNFTLVDGGYVLSHGHKQLMCLARSVLSKAKIILLDEPSAHLDPITYQVIRRVLKQAFAGCTVILCEHRIEAMLDCQRFLVIEESNVWQYDSLQALLSEKSIFQQAISSSEKMRFFQGRHSSKHKPRTQITALKEETEEEVQETRL

I've written a subroutine that opens the file, and reads each sequence one at a time.  For each sequence I would like to add both the gi number at the beginning and the long sequence in capital letters as strings to a growing array.  However, I'm having trouble writing a regular expression to store these values.  Here is my current subroutine, which I tweaked to see if I was actually storing the gi number:

```
sub getFASTA {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    my @FASTA_arr;
    $/ = "\n\n";
    open (my $fh, '<', $filename) or
            die ("Could not open file: $filename");
    while (<$fh>) {
            chomp $_;
            $_ =~ /^>gi|(\d*?)|/s;
            say "$1";
    }
    close $fh;
    #say join(" ", @FASTA_arr);
}
```

However, trying to run this returns:

```
Use of uninitialized value $1 in string at sequenceAlignment.pl line 30, <$fh> chunk 1.
```

This is returned for each sequence, so 100 times in total.

So any idea of what is wrong?  I'm almost certain that it is a problem with the regular expression, because when I changed it to "$_ =~ /(>gi|)/s;", it worked correctly, just with 100 ">gi|"s printing out.

Comment: You need to escape the pipes in the regex: `$_ =~ /^>gi\|(\d*?)\|/s`

Answer (score 0):

| means OR in a regex.  Escape it.  (Seems like perl figured out what you "really" meant when it was at the end of the capture group and didn't have a 2nd operand)

Comment: Thanks man, that was it!  I wasn't thinking about special characters